# Why is the TextChanged event not working in this Xamarin.Android code?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext, xamarin.android

In a Xamarin.Android app, following the example at https://developer.xamarin.com/videos/?v=Activities_and_Intents (19:55) I am trying to assign an event handler to the onclick event of a button, and smilarly to the video above, I'd like not to call a delegate or lambda but rather just call a method defined elsewhere. This is not working in my code, but if I use a delegate it does... Can you explain why?

Also, I am trying to do the same with an EditText, for which I'd like to add event for when text is changed. But this is not working too..

```
public class MainActivity : Activity

{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {   
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        button.Click += delegate { button.Text = "clicked!" };
        // this works

        Button searchButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.searchButton);
        searchButton.Click += SearchButton_Click;

        EditText artistNameEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.artistNameEditText);
        artistNameEditText.TextChanged += artistNameEditText_TextChanged;
    }

    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("button pressed!");
        // this is not working!
    }

    private void artistNameEditText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("text has changed!");
        // this is not working!
    }
}
```

Comment: try making the method protected instead of private

Comment: Are you sure that the event handler is being attached? Is this an abbreviated version of your actual code that might be behaving differently? The snippet you've provided seems like it should be fine.

Comment: @KeithRome the actual code it's basically the same... now I expanded my question to include code for the event Click button, which on the contrary is working fine... can it help?

Comment: @Jason please check again my expanded question, the button click event works, and it's private too..

Comment: Hmm, the fact that the Click event is working makes things more odd. Is it possible to share the layout xml too?

Comment: @KeithRome sure, http://pastebin.com/K1wMmxRr there are two buttons, which both work, and other views that I added just for learning and that I am not actually using...

Comment: @KeithRome I apologize, seems that the other button too in my example is not working! Please see my updated question.

Comment: @KeithRome I apologize once more and big time now... this was all due to a very dumb reason/mistake being that I was not uninstalling the app from my device before pushing the new version to it and I thought that the old version was being overwritten with the new version. I was not making changes to the UI, so it was a bit harder to understand I was running the older version...

Comment: No worries :) that happens sometimes to all of us

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with my code.

The reason it was not working is... I was not uninstalling my app from the device before deploying the new version to it, so I was running the old version over and over again. I took for granted that the old version would be replaced by the new one, just like when you install a new version of the same APK again. It was a bit problematic to spot because I was not making any changes to the UI, but only experimenting with event handlers.

Well, lesson learned, hope this helps someone else...

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy one first implement Android.Text.ITextWatcher in your MainActivity like this:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity, Android.Text.ITextWatcher
    {
        public void AfterTextChanged (Android.Text.IEditable s)
        {

        }

        public void BeforeTextChanged (Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {

        }

        public void OnTextChanged (Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            //were text is changed
        }
...
}
```

and suscribe the TextChangedListener to your element using this

```
EditText artistNameEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.artistNameEditText);
artistNameEditText.AddTextChangedListener (this);
```

Comment: Please don't tell me this is necessary or is the only way... Why the on click event in my example works just as it is?

Comment: Yes is the only way to watch the EditText changes actions in "live" the TextChanged is called when the controls looses his focus if you read the Android docs you find that adding a text change listener is the way to track all edittext text changes (http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher))

Comment: please check my own answer, the reason it was not working was much simpler...... embarrassingly simpler I'd say... :\ But, I have to contradict you though, you don't need all the code you posted, you can just do `artistNameEditText.TextChanged += artistNameEditText_TextChanged;` and it works perfectly...

Comment: First at all you need to know how things works in the root I don't know why you mark answers as an invalid when the issue was an error on your side, Actually the TextChanged binds an internal ITextWatcher implemented on Xamarin side please read the docs before mark an answer as invalid

Comment: Even though you are right on TextChanged binding an internal ITextWatcher, I downvoted your answer because it was a bit misleading in the fact that I had to modify my code the way you said, and that my code was the source of the problem as your answer implied. I also explicitly asked if what you posted was the only way to do it, and you confirmed that. Imagine someone coming here and seeing your answer, they would end up with a lot more complexity in their code that they don't need, and they would also be tricked into thinking that their code had to be wrong.  So, sorry.

Comment: Don't be confused is not a complex thing, is the correct way based on Android docs, from my point of view there no a complex thing just to implement an interface and subscribe it to a control

Comment: Hahaha Coming from you now make sense the kind of question that you made

Answer (score 0):

Its my much simpler to use the Xamarin version of it.

```
textfield.TextChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var abc = 123;
        };
```

Hope that works for you :)

Comment: It will be good whoever has given negative points, to atleast mention why they did so. That's a valid answer that gives exactly the same result. The only difference being its an anonymous method. And is also the preferred way to do it according to the Xamarin method.

Comment: Syntax-wise the code for the event handler in my question was perfectly fine, so your suggestion to rewrite it in another way was a bit misleading. In fact I ended up wasting more time just trying to rewrite the event handler in all different ways and focusing on that. I am not saying I didn't appreciate your effort, but this is not the right answer, did not help me find it and actually sent me a bit off road too, so... Also you are labeling your code "the Xamarin version" but it has nothing to do with Xamarin, it's just another way to write it in C#. Thanks anyway for trying to help though!

Comment: jj_ : I did not quite make up "Xamarin version", I clearly saw that in couple of places while I did my studies. Secondly, I did not have a clue whether you knew the method that I suggested or not. All I did was to help you get the answer. If you had suggested , you need the same way as written. Probably I would not have posted an answer. Anyways all good. Just wanted to let you know how I feel too

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are using Console in android app, just look to the code below and adjast your code and make sure to remove Console statements (use something else such as Toast).

```
    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        btn.Text = "Search Button Clicked!";
        // Now it is working! :)
    }

    private void artistNameEditText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Text has just changed!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        // Now it is working! :)
    }
```